# Input the output of one query into second query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sets of queries. First, I calculate the median in seconds to complete transactions for a given period of time. The second query converts the median time retrieved in the first query to date format (DD:HH:MI:SS).
I manually input the output result (calculated median) of the first query into the second query to get my desired result (days hours minutes seconds), this works well. But I wanted a situation where I could combine these two queries into one without manually inputting the time in the second query. See the queries below:

```
SELECT  TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT, TxnDuration,
PERCENTILE_CONT(.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TxnDuration) OVER() AS MEDIAN 
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT, 
DATEDIFF(SECOND,  TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT) AS TxnDuration
FROM MyTable
WHERE (TxnStartDT >='2023-01-02 00:00' and TxnStartDT <= '2023-01-08 23:59') and  TxnCompleteDT is not null) AS D
```

Output
**MEDIAN
7333**

```
DECLARE @MD DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, 7333,  0)
SELECT --CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @VARDT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' month(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(DAY, @MD) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' day(s) ' 
+ CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @MD) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' hour(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @MD) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' minute(s) ' 
+ CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, @MD) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' second(s)' as 'Median Time'
```

Output
**0 day(s) 2 hour(s) 2 minute(s) 13 second(s)**

I tried to use the CAST function so that I could run the queries once without running the two queries separately. I got errors.

```
SELECT  TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT, TxnDuration,
PERCENTILE_CONT(.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TxnDuration) OVER() AS MEDIAN 
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT, 
DATEDIFF(SECOND,  TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT) AS TxnDuration
FROM MyTable
WHERE (TxnStartDT >='2023-01-02 00:00' and TxnStartDT <= '2023-01-08 23:59') and  TxnCompleteDT is not null) AS D

DECLARE @MD DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, MEDIAN,  0))
SELECT --CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @VARDT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' month(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(DAY, @MD) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' day(s) ' 
+ CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @MD) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' hour(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @MD) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' minute(s) ' 
+ CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, @MD) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' second(s)' as 'Median Time'
```

**Errors**

> Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 32
>  Incorrect syntax near
> 'CAST', expected 'AS'.
>  Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 34
> Must declare the scalar variable "@MD".

Comment: `DECLARE @MD DATETIME = CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, MEDIAN,  0))` this does not make sense. Median is in a different query, and you are missing `AS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
;with cte as(SELECT  TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT, TxnDuration,
cast (DATEADD(SECOND,PERCENTILE_CONT(.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TxnDuration) OVER() ,0)as datetime) AS MEDIAN 
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT, 
DATEDIFF(SECOND,  TxnStartDT, TxnCompleteDT) AS TxnDuration
FROM MyTable
WHERE (TxnStartDT >='2023-01-02 00:00' and TxnStartDT <= '2023-01-08 23:59') and  TxnCompleteDT is not null) AS D)

SELECT  
  CAST(DATEPART(DAY, MEDIAN) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' day(s) ' 
+ CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, MEDIAN) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' hour(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, MEDIAN) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' minute(s) ' 
+ CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, MEDIAN) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' second(s)' as 'Median Time' 
from cte
```

Comment: The query ran but produced a different result (21 day(s) 0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 0 second(s)). Based on my data, the output should be 0 day(s) 2 hour(s) 2 minute(s) 13 second(s).

Comment: see my edit, added the dateadd seconds